# Should I validate relationships in DynamoDB?

Tags: rest, aws-lambda, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

Lets say I have an app where `users` can make `posts`. I store these in a single DynamoDB table using the following design:

```
+--------+--------+---------------------------+
| PK     | SK     | (Attributes)              |
+-----------------+---------------------------+
| UserId | UserId | username, profile, etc... |  <-- user item
| UserId | PostId | body, timestamp, etc...   |  <-- post item
+--------+--------+---------------------------+
```

When a `user` makes a `post`, my Lambda function receives the following data:

```
{
  "userId": <UserId>",
  "body": <Body>,
  etc...
}
```

My question is, should I first verify that the `user` exists before adding the `post` to the table by using `dynamodb.get({PK: userId, SK: userId)`? This would make sure there won't be any orphaned `posts`, but also the function will require both a read and write unit.

One idea I have is to just write the `post`, potentially allowing orphaned `posts`. Then, I could have another Lambda function that runs periodically to find and remove any orphans.

This is obviously a simple case, but imagine a more complex system where objects have multiple relationships. It seems it could easily get very costly to check for relationship existence in these cases.

Comment: UserId should not be part of payload sent by client. It should be determined from the user ticket. otherwise it lets hacker create post in the name of `Barak Obama` and `Donald Trump`. And yes of-course userid should be validated since even if you have separate lambda to remove orphans it will consume some read capacity.

Comment: You are definitely right. I just used this as a simple example of a relationship. Thank you for the advice though for using user tickets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"Then, I could have another Lambda function that runs periodically to find and remove any orphans."* <-- This could get very expensive over time, especially if you plan to do this by [scanning](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Scan.html) the table.

I develop a system built on DynamoDB that has similar relationships, and I validate relationships before saving data because I do not want to have garbage data in my tables.

One option to consider is implicitly testing for the existence of a valid user via authentication & authorization. If a user has passed your auth tests, then you know that they exists, so you can add their posts with confidence.